# Error occur when trying to add the array object of Stripe Transfer

Tags: stripe-payments

I am implementing a stripe demo in which payment will be divided into multiple destination(multiple service provider).In that as i see when i use the below given array for multiple payment then it throws me an syntax error when web page is loaded.

```
//Create a Transfer to a connected account (later):
$transfer = \Stripe\Transfer::create([
  'amount' => 7000,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  'destination' => 'HERE WILL BE STRIPE ACCOUNT ID',
  'transfer_group' => 'ORDER_95',
]);
```

Here below it throws an error when web page is loaded :

[image]

Here below is the code of PHP and JS which i use to do payment.I does not have to disclose the stripe account id so that's why i have wrote "STRIPE ACCOUNT ID" over there.

1) PHP File

[image]

2) JS File

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to know for sure but I suspect that either you've got an empty body in `result`.  You should try just `console.log()`ing the response instead of trying to toString it, and you should also probably check (and log) the `status`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

Comment: I have used `console.log()` to check the reponse.In that response is print in the console tab but in the ajax response nothing is return.When i comment the code of "Stripe Transfer"  then it run perfectly.

Comment: You should add some logging in your server-side code to see what error might be occurring when trying to send the response.  Also probably worth confirming that you're returning something in the PHP file.